# Change Python:Run Python File in Terminal command in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, opencv, visual-studio-code

I am using an anaconda environment in VS code when suddenly the *Run Python File in Terminal* command bound to the green play-button in the top right corner stopped working. It used to input: `python_path file_path/file.py` into the terminal and it worked perfectly fine.

But after running my code in the anaconda prompt program it has now changed to: 
`& conda run -n env_name python file_path/file.py` and now I get a ModuleNotFoundError, that I don't have cv2 installed, which I do.

I can still run the code if I simply input: `python file_path/file.py`. My question is if it is possible to change the command that is bound to *Run Python File in Terminal*. I could not find a solution to this in a couple hours of searching. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you should install opencv to the conda environment. ``conda activate env_name`` and ``conda install opencv``

Comment: If I do that I get the message that `# All requested packages already installed.`. It works if I just type `python file_path/file.py`, so all the modules are installed.

Comment: Does it look like a different environment (like base) is actually being activated?
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/9433

Comment: Thank you. This is the exact problem I have. I downgraded the Python extension in VS Code to 2019.10.44104 and it worked again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution I found was to reinstall the older python plugin and the "conda run -n" command would not be used at runtime.
Reinstallation method, Extension --> Python--manage--> install another version

Comment: Thank you! The issue was fixed by installing version 2019.10.44104 of the Python extension.

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely running into a [bug in conda 4.8](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9578). You can either downgrade the extension until a point release comes out with a fix or simply wait for a fix (hopefully Monday).